# Commiting changes on JDT CompilationUnit

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

Hellou guys

I'm trying to create plugin for eclipse to generate some code,and i've been trying to manipulate sourcecodes with JDT

Here's an example

```
        final ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8); 
        parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
        parser.setSource(copy);
        parser.setResolveBindings(true);

        ASTNode node = parser.createAST(null);

        CompilationUnit unit = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);

        AST ast = unit.getAST();

        MethodDeclaration declaration = ast.newMethodDeclaration();
        declaration.setName(ast.newSimpleName("test"));

        TypeDeclaration typeDeclaration = ( TypeDeclaration )unit.types().get( 0 );
        typeDeclaration.bodyDeclarations().add(declaration);
```

Class before

[image]

Class after(according to toString() of CompilationUnit after running code above)

[image]

Obviously,method declaration has been created as i wanted,but i can't figure out how to commit such changes to underlaying resource.The only way i've found is commit method in ICompilationUnit,but its been deprecated,can you suggest any other way ?

Comment: See this code https://github.com/vogellacompany/codemodify/blob/master/de.simonscholz.codemodify/src/de/simonscholz/junit4converter/JUnit4Converter.java

Answer (score 1):

Ok so thanks to bodo's comment ,i've figure out this way

```
private void saveChanges(ICompilationUnit copy, CompilationUnit unit)
            throws JavaModelException, MalformedTreeException, BadLocationException {

        Document document= new Document(copy.getBuffer().getContents());
        TextEdit edits = unit.rewrite(document, copy.getJavaProject().getOptions(true));
        edits.apply(document);
        copy.getBuffer().setContents(document.get());
        copy.save(null, false);
    }
```